# Internet explorer returns syntax error with arrow function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js

I am trying to use a d3 visualization that works perfect in chrome, but internet explorer throws a syntax error.

The error appears to be on the line:

*d=>color[d.primary]*

```
var bp=viz.bP()
            .data(data)
            .min(12)
            .pad(1)
            .height(h)
            .width(w)
            .barSize(35)
            .fill(d=>color[d.primary]);
```

It seems like IE doesn't support that syntax. Can anyone suggest how it should be written instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this

```
var bp=viz.bP()
            .data(data)
            .min(12)
            .pad(1)
            .height(h)
            .width(w)
            .barSize(35)
            .fill(function(d){
                return color[d.primary]
            });
```

Also, in the future, check out [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) to figure out what you can use in what browsers